# Access Paragraph fields programmatically in custom module

Tags: nodes, paragraphs

I have a Product content type with these fields; title, body, and one entity reference revisions(Paragraph: field_select_module).

I am creating a custom REST API(custom module) to export the fields in the JSON. I am able to print the title and body. Could someone help me to print the paragraph fields which have title and image(Media) and title and image will repeat 3 times. It should be inside this array 'product_list' => array(),

Here is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\drupalup_json_api\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

/**
 * Controller for export json.
 */
class JsonApiController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function data() {
    $json_array = array(
      'data' => array()
    );
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','product_main_categories')->execute();
    $nodes =  Node::loadMultiple($nids);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $json_array = array(
        'id' => $node->get('nid')->value,
        'title' =>  $node->get('title')->value,
        'content' => $node->get('body')->value,
        'product_list' => array(
            
        ),
      );
    }
    return new JsonResponse($json_array);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have gone through this article but can you please tell me how to get the paragraph fields inside a product_list array.

Comment: The same way you do id, title, and content, from the node, only with the paragraphs after you've loaded them.